# How to embed JavaFX SimpleSwingBrowser in Java swing

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I have a [SimpleSwingBrowser](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swing/SimpleSwingBrowser.java.htm) in my Java Swing application. However when it runs, it opens in a new window. Is it possible to open it inside a container in the Swing application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SimpleSwingBrowser` extends `JFrame`, thus `JFrame` is essentially a separate window. If you need to embed `SimpleSwingBrowser` into another `JFrame`, you should rewrite `SimpleSwingBrowser` to extend `Component`.

Comment: Thanks, it was just enought to make it extend from JInternalFrame .